# UPS Error: shipping method is currently unavailable

Tags: shipping, magento-1.6, shipping-methods, ups

I did not understand why I am getting this error for ups shipping "This shipping method is currently unavailable. If you would like to ship using this shipping method, please contact us."

I have this following settings in UPS backend

http://awesomescreenshot.com/082404tl8d.

When I checked shipping_ups.log file. It has following response.

```
    [result] => Array
        (
            [error] => Unable to Connect to tcp://www.ups.com:80. Error #0: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
            [code] => 0
        )

    [__pid] => 15259
)
```

Does anyone has idea, how to fix it. I am using magento 1.6

Comment: does solve your problem ??

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a firewall issue to me, it is not able to connect to UPS.  Test connectivity from the server and also ensure you havent changed the UPS urls in use.

Answer (score 1):

It was a network issue for me..I changed the network and proxy, it started working..Also make sure you have assigned weight to the products and have set maximum allowed weight (greater than the product's weight) in the shipping methods config..

Also check with your firewall..Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late to the party, but we just ran into a similar issue on 2.1.7 that ended up being a typo in our 'Origin' section of the Magento shipping settings. If your origin address does not validate, the shipping options will not display.